# Regex: How to check if there's only whitespaces before selection

Tags: regex

I need to align a specific set of characters on my code but on these conditions:

1. It must be the last thing to appear on the line
2. It must be a "valid" line, meaning there needs to be anything other than whitespaces BEFORE the string

What I've been trying to align is the following:

```
            //Example                                                                  
            //########.#

            LDT     (exampleCode)
//########.#                E       (exampleCode)
            AND     (exampleCode)                    //########.#
            AND     (exampleCode)            //########.#
            MEMO    (exampleCode)                         //########.#
```

I've started to mess around with regex on SublimeText3 for a way to make it such that the above code aligns to this:

```
            //Example                                                                  
            //########.#

            LDT     (exampleCode)
//########.#                E       (exampleCode)
            AND     (exampleCode)                    //########.#
            AND     (exampleCode)                    //########.#
            MEMO    (exampleCode)                    //########.#
```

The "//########.#" being the set of characters that I want to align.

I can already follow the first rule, using the following

```
//[0-9]{8}\.[0-9a-zA-Z]$
```

However the result of this ends up like this:

```
            //Example                                                                  
                                                     //########.#

            LDT     (exampleCode)
//########.#                E       (exampleCode)
            AND     (exampleCode)                    //########.#
            AND     (exampleCode)                    //########.#
            MEMO    (exampleCode)                    //########.#
```

I would like to find a way to check if the line has anything BEFORE the characters that I want to align, so that it only aligns if there's anything coming before it instead of only whitespaces

Comment: In other words, you want to align inline comments for non-empty lines? Do you already know the distance  from the start of the line (in characters) on which you want to move them?

Comment: Yes, precisely. However the distance can vary, since there are blocks of code with just a few characters, in this case a good 30 characters would meet the criteria, but there are exceptions to it since the line can vary tremendously

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pattern, I assume that the `#` are digits as you want to match `[0-9]{8}` 8 digits.

If that is the case, one option might be using 2 capturing groups and use those in the replacement.

```
^(\h*\S+(?:\h+\S+)*)\h+(//[0-9]{8}\.[0-9a-zA-Z])$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of the string
- `(`  Capture group 1

  - `\h*\S+` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars, 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `(?:\h+\S+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `)` Close group
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars (which you want to replace)
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `//[0-9]{8}\.[0-9a-zA-Z]`  Your pattern (note to escape the dot)
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

In the replacement use the 2 groups and fill it with the amount of spaces that you want

`$1                    $2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kYXQxn/1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something in two steps:

- The first step add spaces to each target line to be sure that the comment of the smallest line of code is after the column where the longest code line ends. No need to search the longest line of code, an upper approximative value should suffice. Lets say 100.
- The second step removes useless spaces to align comments. Lets say you want all the comments on column 80.

Feel free to choose other values that better fit your need, but the idea is here.

Checking if there's code before the comment is easy to solve. You have to describe the line from the start and describe a non blank character `\S` before the comment.

1. first step (put the number of spaces needed in the replacement string)

search: `^\h*\S.*\K(?=//\d{8}\.[[:alnum:]]$)`
replacement:

2. second step

search: `^(?=\h*\S.*(//\d{8}\.[[:alnum:]]$))(.{80}).*`
replacement: `$2$1`

Details:

```
^   # anchor for the start of the line
(?=\h*\S.*(//\d{8}\.[[:alnum:]]$)) # lookahead assertion to
  # select only lines with code before (as in the first pattern)
  # and to capture at the same time the comment substring in the
  # capture group $1
(.{80}) # capture the first 80 chars in group $2
.* # consume the end of the line (useless spaces + comment)
```

Since a lookahead is only a zero-width assertion, it does consume characters, this way you can match the number of characters you want from the start of the line with `.{80}`